# OpenTK GameWindow in fullscreen - handle OS shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, opentk

I noticed that if you change your `GameWindow` state to `Fullscreen` you can no longer use system keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (they simply do nothing, BTW I use Windows 7).

Is there a way to fix it? Do I have to catch this shortcuts manually in my application (and trigger appropriate action)?

Comment: What is your GPU? This does not appear to happen on the systems I have tested.

Comment: Alt+F4 doesn't seem to ever do anything fullscreen or not, but Alt+Tab works fine in Fullscreen for me, Windows 7 nVidia GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but I'm posting the answer for anyone Googling this like I did.

You will have to manually register the OnKeyDown event.

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyboardKeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
    if (e.Alt && e.Key == Key.F4)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

This worked for me. If you want it to bring up an "Are you sure?" message or something like that, you can put it in the if statement.